# Type definitions should start with a '{', expecting serialized type 'ErrorResponse', got string starting with: MOCK FOR URL NOT FOUND

Tags: c#, servicestack, moq, xunit

I'm writing a unit test with **Xunit** and **Moq** on a **ServiceStack** microservice.

I can get a unit test of a GET route to work with one class, but with a different class it refuses to work. I'm moq'ing the `ServiceStack.JsonHttpClient.GET` in this route:

```cs
public SampleResponse Get(SampleRequest request)
{
    var myServiceRequest = new SampleService.myRequest() { PrimaryId = request.PrimaryId };
    using (client = ClientFactory.CreateSampleService()) // client is extension of ServiceStack.JsonHttpClient
    {
        // This code runs on local but throws the exception with unit testing
        SampleService.myResponse myResponse = client.Get(myServiceRequest);
        ...
    }
}
```

And here is the test:

```cs
// Arrange
var myServiceRequest = new SampleService.myRequest { PrimaryId = 1234 };
var myServiceResponse = new SampleService.myResponse { ... };

 // assigning the request with the desired response
mockService.MockGet(myServiceRequest, myServiceResponse);

// Act
var request = new ServiceModel.SampleRequest { PrimaryId = 1234 };
 // This calls the above function and fails
var response = frontEndService.Get(request); 

// Assert
Assert.NotEmpty(response.Items);
Assert.Equal(3, response.Items.ANumber);
```

But I get this Exception and InnerException:

> ServiceStack.WebException: 'Not Found'
>
> Inner Exception
>
> SerializationException: Type definitions should start with a '{', expecting serialized type 'ErrorResponse', got string starting with: MOCK FOR URL NOT FOUND

I did an almost identical setup for a simpler class and it works, but this class refuses to unit test correctly. It DOES run fine when ran locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Exception occurs when the JSON doesn’t match the Type you’re trying to deserialize into.

Comment: Hi mythz! I updated my question; I'm getting an ErrorReponse type returned from the GET when I expect the moq to return a OcrWordsResponse. How could I troubleshoot why ServiceStack doesn't process the OcrDocumentRequest type correctly?

Comment: @Zorgarath The Exception suggests the Service threw an Exception, did you try debugging your Service implementation?

Comment: Myself and my team members are all stumped since the service runs fine, but once this one object gets moq'ed and unit tested ServiceStack throws the error. I've been having some trouble finding out more why the exception is thrown.

Comment: @Zorgarath `frontEndService` is your Service class right? so `frontEndService.Get()` is just a method call that's being directly called which you can debug. You're just calling a C# method here. I don't see any serialization either as you're just passing in a typed Request DTO and returning a typed Response DTO. Is your Service making a HTTP call or doing any serialization itself? If it is that's likely where the issue is.

Comment: Yep the `frontEndService.Get()` has a `ServiceStack.JsonHttpClient.Get` inside it, which the latter is throwing the exception. Troubleshooting that `client.Get(ocrServiceRequest)` is where I get stuck. (I updated the question more to include the get code)

Comment: @Zorgarath no-one else will be able to tell what the issue is with your remote call, I'd first check the raw HTTP Request/Response Headers with Fiddler so you can see exactly what's being sent/received which should highlight the issue. Basically the issue looks like the ServiceClient expected to deserialize a Service Error Response object, but instead received the string "MOCK FOR URL NOT FOUND" which is not the serialize ErrorResponse object it was expecting.

Comment: Hi mythz, as it turns out our moq had an incorrect request type that was mapped to the correct response type, and some internal code had obfuscated the origin of the error. We have since fixed it!